# Can I work on an ASP.NET MVC 1 project in Visual Studio 2010 RC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 RC and MVC 2 projects appear in File | New Project, but not MVC 1. Can I target MVC 1 webapps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is [no tooling support](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/10/20/vs10beta2-and-aspnetmvc.aspx) for ASP.NET MVC 1.0 in VS 2010, but if you can live without *Add View*, *Add Controller* etc, you can target that framework.

Answer (score 1):

BONUS: If you decide to migrate to MVC2 this [Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/11/23/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2-beta-updated.aspx) will save you a headache ; )